# ElasticSearch: plugin Phonetic analayzer in rails 4

Tags: plugins, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

I am trying to implement phonetic plug-in (https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-analysis-phonetic) in elastic search.

To implement this plug-in i had refereed the below link
http://blog.jessitron.com/2012/04/configuring-soundex-in-elasticsearch.html

Tested with following steps :

1. curl localhost:9200/_shutdown -XPOST
2. curl localhost:9200/anyindexname -XPUT
   {"ok":true,"acknowledged":true}
3. curl "localhost:9200/anyindexname/_analyze?analyzer=search_soundex&pretty=true" -d 'bunch of words'

It throws me an error such as

{
  "error" : "ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to find analyzer [search_soundex]]",
  "status" : 400
}

Guys, I need your help to solve this problem.....

Comment: Got an alternate for gem tire, gem searchkick (but still tire contribute searchkick).  It provides a standard phonetic search added with with several other features...  for futher references http://ankane.github.io/searchkick.  But eagerly searching for manual customizable search using tire and elastic search,.